# Key Error Trying to plot multiple bar charts from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Reason why I am loading the df from the .csv is because another file creates the csv and then this file will access it (maybe this is an issue? not sure)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('MAIN_DATAFRAME.csv')

def plot_graph_1(MAIN_DATAFRAME):
        df1 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc[['Bots']]
        df1 = df1.transpose()
        df2 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc[['Speed']]
        df2 = df2.transpose()
        df3 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc[['Weight']]
        df3 = df3.transpose()
        df4 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc[['Chargers']]
        df4 = df4.transpose()


        ax = df1.plot(kind='bar')
        df2.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar')
        df3.plot(ax=ax,kind='bar')
        df4.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar')
        ax.bar(ax, df1)
        plt.show()


plot_graph_1(df)
```

So I would like to have this Dataframe be plotted and ideally the bar charts will share axis and be different collors so that they can be distinguised when stacked on each other.

btw here is the dataframe:

|  | Run 1 | Run 2 | Run 3 | Run 4 | Run 5 | Run 6 | Run 7 | Run 8 | Run 9 | Run 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bots | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| Speed | 1791 | 2359 | 2996 | 3593 | 4105 | 4551 | 4631 | 4656 | 4672 | 4674 |
| Weight | 612 | 733 | 810 | 888 | 978 | 1059 | 1079 | 1085 | 1090 | 1092 |
| Chargers | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

I tried changing how I access the dataframe values. I also tried changing brackets from: df2 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc[['Speed']] to df2 = MAIN_DATAFRAME.loc['Speed'] and still get a key error.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the whole DataFrame and then you can plot it like this:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data from CSV
df = pd.read_csv(
    "3.csv",
    index_col=0
)

# Define plotting function
def plot_bars_from_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> plt.Axes:
    """Plot bar chart from DataFrame."""

    df = df.transpose()
    ax = df.plot(
        kind="bar"
    )

    return ax


# Call function
plot_bars_from_df(df)
```

You'll get the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMrCa.png)

However, "Bots" and "Charger" are few orders of magnitude smaller than the other columns so it doesn't make much sense to plot them together.